# OpenCV on linux - Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd3

Tags: camera, jpeg, opencv

I am running some code in openCV on my linux mint machine to obtain images from my webcam and do some image processing. However when I run this code the images seem to be corrupt. I keep getting this message in my terminal, while my code is working:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd4
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd5
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd2
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd3
```

The code:

```
 int main()
{

    cv::Mat frame;

    VideoCapture webcam;


    if (!webcam.open(0))
    {
        cout << "file not opened"<<endl;
        waitKey(0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
          Mat frame;
          webcam >> frame;
          if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream
          imshow("this is you, smile! :)", frame);
          if( waitKey(10) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC
    }
}
```